# Google Pay is not working on edge and Firefox in mobile devices And its working fine in desktop for all the browsers

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, iframe, vuex

I have worked on Google pay by using VueJS. and its working fine in all the web browsers but not working in mobile browsers like edge and firefox and working in chrome.

When we click on "GooglePay" button the flowing popup is keep on rendering but not working
[image]

When i observe in console.. its showing error like

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://example.com" from 
accessing a cross-origin frame.

at hasOwnProperty (<anonymous>)
at hasOwn (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:192:27)
at observe (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:933:18)
at Cd.reactiveSetter [as Va] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js:1008:35)
at Cd.show (https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js:213:528)
at https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js:290:341
```

issue is only in edge and firefox on mobile devices not in  desktop devices.

Please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

That is what I see you have a cross-origin error. This error occurs when a web page tries to access a resource from a different domain, protocol, or port than the one that served the web page. This is a security feature implemented by web browsers to prevent malicious websites from accessing sensitive information from other websites.

To fix this issue, you need to ensure that the Google Pay API is being loaded from the same origin as your web page. You can do this by hosting the Google Pay API on your own server or by using a CDN that supports CORS:

1. Host the Google Pay API on your own server: Instead of loading the Google Pay API directly from Google's servers, you can host it on your own server. This way, the API will be served from the same origin as your web page, and you won't encounter any cross-origin issues.
2. Use a CDN that supports CORS: If you prefer to use a CDN to host the Google Pay API, make sure that the CDN supports CORS. This will allow the API to be loaded from a different domain while still being accessible from your web page's origin.
3. Check if your website is registered for the Google Pay API: Ensure that you have completed the process to register your website for the Google Pay API. This may involve requesting production access and a review of your website's use of the API through the Google Pay and Wallet Console
4. Verify that your website is using the Google Pay API in a secure context: The Google Pay API can only be used on websites in a secure context. Make sure that your website is using HTTPS instead of HTTP to access the API
5. Register your public encryption key with Google: If you are using DIRECT tokenizationSpecification type integration, you must register your public encryption key with Google via the Google Pay and Wallet Console

More information you can find [here](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/support/troubleshooting) and [here](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/tutorial?hl=en).

It is possible also to add the following tag to the public/index.html file in your Vue.js project:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">
```

This tag tells the browser not to send the Referer header when making requests to other domains. This can help resolve some CORS (cross-origin resource sharing) issues.

The Referer header is a HTTP header that contains the URL of the web page that the user was on before they clicked a link to the current page. By default, the Referer header is sent with every request made by the browser, including requests to other domains. This can cause CORS issues when the web page tries to access resources from a different domain than the one that served the web page.

By adding the no-referrer meta tag to the head section of your HTML document, you are telling the browser not to send the Referer header when making requests to other domains. This can help resolve some CORS issues by preventing the browser from sending information about the previous page's URL to the server hosting the resource being requested.

More information about the meta tag "referrer" you can find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy)